# Como salvar os valores dos histogramas de múltiplas imagens em um único array em Python?

Tags: python, array, imagem, numpy

Tenho uma pasta com várias imagens, devo percorrer todas essas imagens da pasta e salvar todos esses valores em um array (X, por exemplo). Como posso fazer isso?

Atualmente possuo esse código para percorrer a pasta com as imagens e efetuar a leitura das imagens, mas não sei como salvar os histogramas em um único array. Alguém pode ajudar?

```
from skimage.io import imread_collection
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
Import numpy as np

#your path 
col_dir = 'images2/*.png'

images = imread_collection(col_dir)

for image in images:
  cv2_imshow(image)
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a melhor solução seja:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import glob

matrix = []

for filepath in glob.glob(os.path.join('lateral/', '*.png')):
  with open(filepath) as f:
    img = cv2.imread(f.name, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    histo = cv2.calcHist ([img], [0], None, [25], [0, 25])

    # plt.plot(histo)
    # plt.show()
    # print(histo)

    matrix.append([f.name.split("/")[1], histo])

for item in matrix:
  print(item[0]) # Image name
  print(item[1:]) # Histo
```

Com "matrix" sendo o array com os valores iniciais de cada o nome das imagens e os valores subsequentes o valor de cada campo do histograma.